# Partial View via Ajax all Javascript References are broken

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a PartialView in my MVC Appliction, which returns my View if there are any Errors in the ModelState. In the _Layout site are many javascript ( jQuery, JQuery.validate, ... ) references which i use in the partai view. 
Here the Code:
Javascript submit:

```
$(function () {
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (!result.Success) {
                    $('#formcontent').html(result); // Show PartailView with Validationmessages
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Parent Site:

```
<div id="formcontent" class="tc-form">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial( "_ConfigurationPartial", Model ); }
</div>
```

Partial View:

```
@model SettingsViewModel
@{ Layout = null; }
@using( Html.BeginForm() )
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary( false, SystemStrings.ValidationSummaryMessage )
    <ol class="last">
       <li class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor( m => m.PasswordMinimumLength )
            @Html.EditorFor( m => m.PasswordMinimumLength )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.PasswordMinimumLength, "*" )
        </li>
        <li class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor( m => m.PasswordNeverExpires )
            @Html.EditorFor( m => m.PasswordNeverExpires )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.PasswordNeverExpires, "*" )
        </li>
        <li class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor( m => m.PasswordExpirationValue )
            @Html.EditorFor( m => m.PasswordExpirationValue )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.PasswordExpirationValue, "*" )
            @Html.EditorFor( m => m.PasswordExpirationUnit )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor( m => m.PasswordExpirationUnit, "*" )
        </li>
    </ol>
    <div class="tc-form-button">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" title="Save" class="t-button t-state-default" />
        @Html.ActionLink( "Cancel", "Configuration", "System", null, new { @class = "t-button" } )
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PasswordNeverExpires').change(function () {
            setState($(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });

    function setState(isDisabled) {
        if (isDisabled) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Configuration( SettingsViewModel model )
    {
        if( !ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            this.PopulateViewData();
            return PartialView( "_ConfigurationPartial", model );
        }
        else
        {
            // ... do save
            return Json( new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
        }
    }
```

If the partialView is load via ajax all my Javascript are broken. There is no second ajax submit, it is a normal post. So the partialvew is rendered without any layout informations. It seems that all the javascript references are not found. Is there any way to refresh the DOM or something else? Must i have all the javascript in the PartailView? What is the correct way for this?

Regards

Comment: If the javascript is in the Layout file, and you do not send this to your View, my guess is that it wont work. Perhaps you could put your JavaScript in the _ViewStart.cshtml ? But im not sure.

Comment: Or you could out your javascript in a seperate file and reference that in your partialview which does not include the layout file

Comment: Where is your jquery script tag?

Answer (score 0):

This code is outside of Partial View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   var oldvalue=$('#PasswordNeverExpires').val();
   $('#PasswordNeverExpires').change(function(){
      oldvalue=$(this).val();
   })
});
</script>
```

Then I change your code in PartialView a little:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if($('#PasswordNeverExpires').val()!=oldvalue){
            //your scripts put here.
        }
    });
```

The above code was not tested but It should work.

Comment: The change function works correct. But all referenced scipt files (jQuery is referenced by _Layout.cshtml) are lost. So jQuery is not found, after the view is loaded via ajax

Comment: Are you sure? Try some simple jQuery script in Partial View for testing that if it work or not. If not, you should check your script's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you bind the submit event to the form when the page is loaded for the first time. When you reload the form through ajax you need to rebind the submit event to your new form.

You can also `live` bind the event, which you do only once

```
$("form").live("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                if (!result.Success) {
                    $('#formcontent').html(result); // Show PartailView with Validationmessages
                }
                else {}
            }
        });
    }

});
```

read more [here](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)